# Get text after brackets

Tags: php, regex

I would like to solve the following problem:

I fetch mails via imap; now I use regexp to get the text between two quare brackets (Ticket-ID).

For example: `[Ticket-ID: 84824] Re:Test`

```
preg_match("/\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]/", $mail->subject, $matches)
```

gets 84824 as result - but how can I get "Re:Test" or just "Test" with PHP?

Now I would like to get the pure subject without any ticket-numbers and so on. How can I solve that?

Comment: Something like this, with capturing groups: [`\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]\s*(?:(Re):)?(\S*)`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7bX0/2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one more capturing group in your regex pattern like this:

```
preg_match("/\[Ticket-ID: (\S+)\]\s*(.*)/", $mail->subject, $matches)
```

It will capture "Re:Test" in the second match, so you can retrieve it from `$matches[2]`

Comment: This already works great - but if there is a space between the last bracket and the "Test" this space is getting covered, too: So it is " Test" instead of "Test"

Comment: @MyFault, oops... it should be greedy `\s*` there before second capturing group, not lazy `\s*?`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
\[[\s\S]+\][\s]*(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK4vQ0/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$str ='[Ticket-ID: 84824] Re:Test';
preg_match('/\[[\s\S]+\][\s]*(.*)/',$str,$matches);
echo $matches[1];

?>
```

Output :

```
Re:Test
```

If you want only `Test`, use following regex:

```
\[[\s\S]+\][\s]*Re:(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string='[Ticket-ID: 84824] Re:Test';
$bracket_location=strpos($string,'] ');
$subject=substr($string,$bracket_location+2,strlen($string)-$bracket_location+2);
```

Loop through your matches and your $subject will give you the Re:Test.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this regex:** `\[[^:]+:\s*(\d+)\]`

```
$re = "/\\[[^:]+:\\s*(\\d+)\\]/"; 
$str = "[Ticket-ID: 84824] Re:Test"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX5kY8/1)